# Permanent water marks etched onto glass

Tags: everyday-chemistry, glass

We are noticing some permanent marks etched onto various glass parts we use in lighting products that cannot be removed. These appear regardless of the type of water (tap, DI etc. Our DI water is purified to 2us/cm).

No matter the amount of rubbing with IPA or micro-fibre cloth, we cannot remove them, so it seems to be etched.

Is there some process going on here where water can somehow etch / eat the glass? Something else that we are not aware of?

[image: Glass with water marks]

Comment: Etching would be a permanent damage, but I doubt it's that.

Comment: Can you try gently rubbing a cotton ball soaked in vinegar for some time? Is it possible to remove the glass? IPA does *not* remove water scales and it is not meant for removing water spots.

Comment: Could be something like https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69797/e-glass-degradation-in-water but I'm sceptical

Comment: Low *conductivity* water is not necessarily free of *non-polar* contaminants. Let some of the water dry on a precleaned microscope slide and look for spots.

Comment: We tried cleaning / soaking with vinegar - no change at all. Not even a razor blade appears to affect the spots.